# Get the data of the dragged item on drop in CDK drag drop Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk, angular-cdk-drag-drop

I have this data which i'm dragging

```
  <tbody cdkDropList [cdkDropListData]="ListData">
                              <tr *ngFor="let list of ListData" cdkDrag>
                               ...
                               </tr>
  </tbody>
```

i want to drag a particular row and drop in second container

```
 <li *ngFor="let user of userData; index as i;"> 
  <div cdkDropList [cdkDropListData]="UserList" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event,user.Id)" cdkDropListSortingDisabled> 

..
</li>
```

i want to get the dragged item data in drop function

```
drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>,Id) {
event.previousContainer.data[event.previousIndex];
}
```

tried the above code but this is picking the current drag data

any solution

thanks

Comment: You didn't set the `[cdkDropListConnectedTo]`? Wonder how this can even work... [Here's a good sample](https://bootstrap.mintplayer.com/additional-samples/drag-drop) and [here's the code](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/tree/master/apps/ng-bootstrap-demo/src/app/pages/additional-samples/drag-drop)

Answer (score 1):

For that you can use the `cdkDragData` attribute:

Inside your `cdkDropList` which is fed by `ListData` you have instances of lists which are rendered as `cdkDrag` elements. Here you should add the `[cdkDragData]` attribute, whose data is determined by each `list` object. In your situation it should look something like that:

```
<tbody cdkDropList [cdkDropListData]="ListData">
   <tr *ngFor="let list of ListData" cdkDrag [cdkDragData]="list">
      ...
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

The object content of each list can then be accessed on a drop event in your drop function as follows:

```
drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>,Id) {
   //save the dragged object data to a constant variable
   const draggedItemData = event.item.data;
}
```

Like Pieterjan mentioned you should also look into the [`[cdkDropListConnectedTo]`](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview#transferring-items-between-lists) attribute which lets you drop draggable elements between different lists pretty simply.